# Facebook Open graph - Unknown path components

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

```
{
"error": {
"message": "Unknown path components: /[your_namespace]:[your_action]",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 2500
}
```

I got the error above after trying to publish an action(watch/movie action I already created for my app).

How to solve this problem?
I tried to search but it doesn't work at all.

Here is my js code.

```
     
    
      OG Tutorial App
       
       
       
       
       
      

      
      function postCook()
      {
          FB.api(
            '/me/xxx:watch',
            'post',
            { movie: 'http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/the_hobbit_an_unexpected_journey/' },
            function(response) {
               if (!response || response.error) {
                   var output = '';
                   for (property in response.error) {
                     output += property + ': ' + response.error[property]+'; ';
                   }
                  alert( output);
               } else {
                  alert('Cook was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
               }
            });
      }
      
    
    
      
      
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
          FB.init({
            appId      : 'yyy', // App ID
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
          });
        };

        // Load the SDK Asynchronously
        (function(d){
          var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
          js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
          d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));
      

    
      

      Stuffed Cookies
```

Comment: PS - The code above based on this tutorial "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/opengraph-tutorial/#authenticate"

Comment: Are you sure you're posting to the correct endpoint? the error message implies no - what is the sample code shown to you in the Open Graph settings for the app doing? If it's the built-in watch action it should be POSTing to /me/video.watches

Comment: Thanks @Igy. I make it work now by using /me/video.watches